# Windows shares - can't access

Tags: windows, network-shares

I've recently reinstalled my laptop. I have a ,main machine which has all the programs install files on. Before i reinstalled the laptop i was able to access the shares on the machine fine, after the reinstall it keeps telling me that i don't have permission. Previously it would ask for the pcs username/password but its not doing that. Other machines are still able to access the shares fine, and i can remote desktop it from the laptop but not connect to the shares. The pc shows up under networks. The PC is running winows 7 and the laptop windows 10. I can access the laptop fine from the pc but not the other way around.

I get "You do not have permission to access \PC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was something to do with a windows update. Once windows had updated on the laptop it connected fine